# How to change both negative and Nan column value to Zero in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Data frame is like :

```
    A    B
10  AAA  0.0333
20  BBB  -67
30  CCC -0.98
40  DDD  NaN
```

How do I change the column B values (only negative and NaN to 0)

So far I tried Like :

```
df[df< 0 ] = 0 
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

But is there a efficient to do both in a single command ? I am new to pandas. Please tell me if it is not the best way to do so.

Comment: I'm no pandas expert, but to me the two-liner given in the question seems far more readable then the answers so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can check [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
df.loc[(df['B'] < 0) | (df['B'].isnull()), 'B'] = 0

      A       B
10  AAA  0.0333
20  BBB  0.0000
30  CCC  0.0000
40  DDD  0.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the property that `NaN` isn't positive or negative so if we negate the positive mask you also return the `NaN` values and we can set these to `0` also:

```
In [14]:
df.loc[~(df['B'] > 0), 'B'] = 0
df

Out[14]:
      A       B
10  AAA  0.0333
20  BBB  0.0000
30  CCC  0.0000
40  DDD  0.0000
```